# Is it possible to increase/decrease the Delay Time after the Delay block was triggered a certain amount?

Tags: delay, anylogic

Hello I want to increase the time of a Delay Block in my Flow Chart after the Delay Block was triggered a certain amount. My Process Flow Look like this [image: Process Flow]
I tried to increase the time manually by using a slider but this only works for capacity and not the time. Is there a possibility to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

you can easily do that by making the delay time a function

in the delay you write delayFunction()

and you create a function that will return a double that will have something like

```
if(condition is met) return x;
else return y;
```

Comment: Hello @Felipe Thank you for your help, but It does not work, it seems like I am doing something wrong. I created a follow question.